# R: Calling objects within character string

Tags: r

```
> foo <- as.character(c(0, 2))
> foo
[1] "0" "2"
> foo[1]
[1] "0"
> foo[2]
[1] "2"

> as.character("0-2")
[1] "0-2"  #this is the output I want from the command below:

> as.character("foo[1]-foo[2]")
[1] "foo[1]-foo[2]"  # ... was hoping to get "0-2"
```

I tried some variations of `eval(parse())`, but same problem.  I also tried these simple examples:

```
> as.character("as.name(foo[1])")
[1] "as.name(foo[1])"
> as.character(as.name("foo[1]"))
[1] "foo[1]"
```

Any chance of getting something simple like `as.character("foo[1]-foo[2]")` to display `"0-2"`?

**UPDATE**

Similar example (with a much longer string):

```
> lol <- as.character(seq(0, 20, 2))
> lol
 [1] "0"  "2"  "4"  "6"  "8"  "10" "12" "14" "16" "18" "20"

 > c(as.character("0-2"), as.character("2-4"), as.character("4-6"), as.character("6-8"), as.character("8-10"), as.character("10-12"), as.character("12-14"),as.character("14-16"),as.character("16-18"),as.character("18-20"))
 [1] "0-2"   "2-4"   "4-6"   "6-8"   "8-10"  "10-12" "12-14" "14-16" "16-18" "18-20"
```

I would like to be able to actually call the object `lol` from within my character string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `paste` with the `collapse` argument

```
paste(foo, collapse='-')
#[1] "0-2"
```

If we need to `paste` adjacent elements together, remove the first and last elements of 'lol' and then `paste` it together with the `sep` argument.

```
paste(lol[-length(lol)], lol[-1], sep='-')
#[1] "0-2"   "2-4"   "4-6"   "6-8"   "8-10"  "10-12" "12-14" "14-16" "16-18"
#[10] "18-20"
```

Comment: My actual string is much longer though, collapsing won't work for me... perhaps you can provide an example of dealing with a longer string like this.  I've updated my question...

Comment: Just curious... if you're removing the first and last elements, how does it know to still create `"0-2"` and `"18-20"`, if both 0 and 20 were removed?

Comment: @warship In the first vector `lol[-length(lol)]` the last element is removed, and in the second one, it is the first one.  Now, the lengths are the same, only thing is that the corresponding elements are displaced.

Comment: But wouldn't that "technically" do `paste(20, 0, sep = '-')`, which would give `"20-0"`?  Your command is so cool, I'm just trying to understand it better (for my own learning).

Comment: @warship To understand it better, create a `data.frame`  and check the corresponding elements in each vector i.e. `d1 <- data.frame(v1= lol[-length(lol)], v2=lol[-1])`

Comment: @warship No, it is [Arun](http://stackoverflow.com/users/559784/arun), the coauthor of data.table.

Comment: @warship I would like to keep this profile anonymous

Comment: @warship I got your email.  I will contact you once I reach home (as my personal emails are blocked at the company)

Comment: Perfect, many thanks!  I removed some of my comments above to keep this answer/comments section clean and relevant to the OP itself.

Comment: Plus one on comment and answer again :-))